# What are the practical uses of gradle in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gradle, gradle-eclipse

***Am posting the below query after failed to understand the practical purpose of Gradle in selenium..***

I am quite successful in using selenium webdriver without using Gradle or any other build tool.
I have seen Selenium developers using Gradle as a build tool for their selenium projects. I fail to see the reason behind using Gradle as a build tool except dependency management. I understand that it is crucial in java development projects.

I have explored a lot as to why we need to use Gradle.. what is the practical use in a selenium project..

**Please correct me if am wrong..** As per my knowledge,In a selenium project,No one requires to do continuous build(If any changes made to source every time) or perform some operation after build except few stuffs like deploy jar in some location.... Because, we would make that as part of execution plan...

Being in Automation for quite some time below are the things that i use to perform and believe most of the projects would go in the same way..

1. No need to perform any task after saving my script every time
2. After developing the script, schedule as a batch for execution...
3. Heard, using build tool only for dependencies management

Below are my queries:-

1. What can be achieved in  gradle(Except dependencies), I understand that we can put up tasks in the build file so that it will be executed after every build.. like creating a file or put jar in some location..Could you please explain me, what kind of realtime tasks that we would need to perform after / during the build..
2. What else can be done  with gradle- selenium  to utilize it in a maximum level...

Comment: Have a read through this: http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

Comment: Thanks @SiKing , I will look in to the post

Answer (score 0):

We can build Check in , check out mechanism for selenium codes. People working from different machines can do check out , do the changes then commit and push the code to the master and check in the code.

Users can create their own build mechanisms. Running the test suite is also quite simple in Gradle